# Java regex newline matches with tabs or space error

Tags: java, regex

I have an unwanted behaviour with `Pattern.matches()` method.

I want my regex to not detect newline character.

The next code returns true, but I don't know why:

```
    String text = "\n";

    if(Pattern.matches("\\t|\\s",text)){
        System.out.println("True");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("False");
    }
```

What should I change in the regex to return false?

Comment: What is weird here? `\s` matches all whitespaces including newline

Comment: \s is whitespace --> \n is a whitespace.

Comment: `\s` includes `\t`, so `\t|\s` is the same as just `\s`.

Comment: I wanted to match single spaces and tabs, not the newline symbol.

Comment: In that case just `\h` to match any horizontal whitespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\\s` includes all whitespace, which in turn includes new lines.

See [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> \s    A whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]

Since you are invoking `matches` with a one-character `String`, the condition will return `true`.
If you only want to match "%20" whitespace, you can use an actual space in your condition instead of `\\s`:

`if(Pattern.matches("\\t| ",text)){`

Answer (score 1):

As per [Pattern API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), `\s` stands for `a whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`. Thus, it will match any of those.

You can either list each individual character you want to match, or you can use operators such as `|` (either-of) and `!` (not). If you're going through text line-by-line, you could also use `^` (beginning of a line) and `$` (end of a line) pseudo-characters.